# Mobile vision face detector slow in other function than onCreate

Tags: android, performance, bitmap, face-detection, vision-api

I am facing an issue with mobile vision, the face detector is very slow, this is when I run the code in a function that is not the onCreate. The detect is done after 14 seconds. But when I first run the detect code in onCreate it loads within a second. I have tried this [Google Mobile Vision: Poor FaceDetector performance without CameraSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34132444/google-mobile-vision-poor-facedetector-performance-without-camerasource) . And I have watched this post  [mobile vision API takes too long to detect face](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43727348/mobile-vision-api-takes-too-long-to-detect-facebut) but the answer is about the bitmap and this is not the problem. Below is given more information about the scenarios.

In scenario 1 I start the detect after I clicked on a button. But then the first time I run the detector, there is a delay of 14 or 15 seconds. The second time I run the detector it runs within 1 second. The memory and CPU seem normal.
Here is the code:

```
private ImageButton mTakePictureButton;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTakePictureButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.take_picture_button);
    mTakePictureButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.take_picture_button:
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.camera_example);
            SparseArray<Face> faces = getFaceArrayFromBitmap(bmp);//<----
            break;
    }
}
private SparseArray<Face> getFaceArrayFromBitmap(Bitmap bmp){
    FaceDetector detector = new FaceDetector.Builder(this)
            .setTrackingEnabled(false)
            .setMode(FaceDetector.FAST_MODE)
            .setClassificationType(FaceDetector.NO_CLASSIFICATIONS)
            .setLandmarkType(FaceDetector.NO_LANDMARKS)
            .build();
    // Create a frame from the bitmap and run face detection on the frame.
    Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(bmp).build();
    SparseArray<Face> faceArray = detector.detect(frame);// <--- First time takes 14/15 seconds
    detector.release();
    return faceArray;
}
```

In scenario 2, where I run the face detector in the onCreate for the first time, it only takes 1 second to run the detector code.

```
private ImageButton mTakePictureButton;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTakePictureButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.take_picture_button);
    mTakePictureButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.camera_example);
    SparseArray<Face> faces = getFaceArrayFromBitmap(bmp);// <-----
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.take_picture_button:

            break;
    }
}
private SparseArray<Face> getFaceArrayFromBitmap(Bitmap bmp){
    FaceDetector detector = new FaceDetector.Builder(this)
            .setTrackingEnabled(false)
            .setMode(FaceDetector.FAST_MODE)
            .setClassificationType(FaceDetector.NO_CLASSIFICATIONS)
            .setLandmarkType(FaceDetector.NO_LANDMARKS)
            .build();
    // Create a frame from the bitmap and run face detection on the frame.
    Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(bmp).build();
    SparseArray<Face> faceArray = detector.detect(frame);// <-- Now it takes only 1 second the first time
    detector.release();
    return faceArray;
}
```

I also saw the source code of mobile vision there is a bug, but this does not look like a problem for me because in the detect, it does not crash.

> /**
>    * This is a workaround for a bug in the face detector, in which either very small images (i.e.,
>    * most images with dimension < 147) and very thin images can cause a crash in the native face
>    * detection code.  This will add padding to such images before face detection in order to avoid
>    * this issue.
>
> *
>    * This is not necessary for use with the camera, which doesn't ever create these types of
>    * images.
>
> *
>    * This detector should wrap the underlying FaceDetector instance, like this:
>    *
>    * Detector safeDetector = new SafeFaceDetector(faceDetector);
>    *
>    * Replace all remaining occurrences of faceDetector with safeDetector.
>    */

Comment: Can it be that facedetector loads some libs and do some other setup first time (e.g. starts service)?

Comment: @sandrstar It indeed does in the very first time of running the detector. But I have run the detector already multiple times. So, in this case, it does not make sense, just because in the onCreate it runs within 1 second. And when I run it in another function, it has a delay of 14 seconds.