# Google Vision Face detect takes a long time

Tags: android, face-detection, google-vision

Copying the code directly from google: [link](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/face-detection/index.html?index=..%2F..index#4)

gives me a 7 second wait time for the face to be detected, using a 2MB image. If I compress the bitmap by a factor of 10, it gives me a 0.05 second face detection time. However nowhere else can I find people suggesting you should compress the bitmap before running facedetection, in fact the docs suggest it should only take 10ms to detect a face, and it does it in real time when i use the camera as the image source.

Related unanswered question: 
[mobile vision API takes too long to detect face](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43727348/mobile-vision-api-takes-too-long-to-detect-face)

Just wondering if this is normal, or I am doing something wrong:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

private int FACE_DETECTION_RATIO_MINIMUM = 10;
FaceDetector detector;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: 1");

            ImageView myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inMutable=true;
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                    getApplicationContext().getResources(),
                    R.drawable.test2,
                    options);

            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: 2");

            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: width: " + myBitmap.getWidth() + " height: " + myBitmap.getHeight());


            Paint myRectPaint = new Paint();
            myRectPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
            myRectPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
            myRectPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: 3");


            Bitmap tempBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(myBitmap.getWidth(), myBitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
            Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap, myBitmap.getWidth()/10, myBitmap.getHeight() /10, false);
            Log.d(TAG, "scaled width: " + scaledBitmap.getWidth() + " height: " + scaledBitmap.getHeight());
            //tempBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, tempBitmap)
            Canvas tempCanvas = new Canvas(tempBitmap);
            Canvas tempCanvasScaled = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);

            tempCanvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, 0, 0, null);
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: 4");


            FaceDetector faceDetector = new
                    FaceDetector.Builder(getApplicationContext()).setTrackingEnabled(false).setMode(FAST_MODE).setLandmarkType(NO_LANDMARKS).setClassificationType(NO_CLASSIFICATIONS)
                    .build();
            if(!faceDetector.isOperational()){
                new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext()).setMessage("Could not set up the face detector!").show();
                return;
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: 5");



            Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(myBitmap).build();
            Frame frameScaled = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(scaledBitmap).build();
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: 5.1");
            SparseArray<Face> faces = faceDetector.detect(frameScaled);


         -->>   SparseArray<Face> faces2 = faceDetector.detect(frame); <-- Takes 7 seconds

            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: 6");

            for(int i=0; i<faces.size(); i++) {
                Face thisFace = faces.valueAt(i);
                float x1 = thisFace.getPosition().x;
                float y1 = thisFace.getPosition().y;
                float x2 = x1 + thisFace.getWidth();
                float y2 = y1 + thisFace.getHeight();
                tempCanvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(x1, y1, x2, y2), 2, 2, myRectPaint);

                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: x,y,x,y: " + x1 +", " + y1 + ", " +  x2 +", " + y2);
            }

            for(int i=0; i<faces2.size(); i++) {
                Face thisFace = faces2.valueAt(i);
                float x1 = thisFace.getPosition().x;
                float y1 = thisFace.getPosition().y;
                float x2 = x1 + thisFace.getWidth();
                float y2 = y1 + thisFace.getHeight();
                tempCanvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(x1, y1, x2, y2), 2, 2, myRectPaint);

                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: x,y,x,y: " + x1 +", " + y1 + ", " +  x2 +", " + y2);
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: 5");
            myImageView.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),tempBitmap));

            faceDetector.release();

            //cropImage(x1,y1,x2,y2);


        }
    });


}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue with vision 17.0.2/18.0.0 versions and I overcame it with downgrading vision library version.

You can use these setup

for top-level build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    //Google analytics
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
}
```

for app-level build.gradle

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:16.2.0'

}
```

if you are using analytics or firebase, these version is compatibility with vision 16.2.0

```
dependencies {

        //Google analytics
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.6'

        //firebase
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'

}
```